# In actionscript, why is my static class member variable not the same when accessed from different parts of my app?

Tags: actionscript-3, static, variables, flash, member

I have an actionscript class with a static member variable defined.

```
public class A
{
     public static var x:int;
}
```

When I try to access it from different parts in my code I don't get the same value in each spot.

```
A.x
```

I am accessing the variable in different modules that are loaded, so they are all in their own separate .swf file.  Could this by why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an application domain problem. The main swf and the modules seem to be accessing their own copies of the A class. You should probably change the way you load your modules.

Check this out:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#applicationDomain
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html